# How can I set add_executable WIN32 property or not depending on the build type?

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake

This fails with the error "Cannot find source file: WIN32. Tried extensions..."

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} $<$<CONFIG:Release>:WIN32> main.cpp)
```

I need this in order to launch the app in the console in Debug mode and being able to read information printed to the console.

And as far as I know it's wrong and is advised agains in the cmake docs to check `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` being `Release` directly.

Comment: Can you try `set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE $<CONFIG:Release>)` instead?

Comment: @vre Thank you! It indeed works! (I can accept it as an answer if you want).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed you cannot use generator expressions for the WIN32 keyword in the `add_executable` command.

Instead, try setting the corresponding property `WIN32_EXECUTABLE` on the target:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE $<CONFIG:Release>)
```